# Changing Selected Option Select menu .attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pre-fill a form that containes select menu's, using JSON, i am using the key as the #id tags for the select menu's
but i cant seem to get it to work i have tried different selectors but still no luck,

here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     var p = {
         "weight":"39",
         "height":"1.24",
         "age":"34"
     };

     for (var key in p) {
         if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

             if ($("#" + key + " option [value=" + p[key] + "]").length) {
                 $("#" + key + " option [value=" + p[key] + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
             }

         }
     }
 });

 <select id="age">
 <option value="33">33</option>
 <option value="34">34</option>
 </select>

 <select id="height">
 <option value="1.25">1.25</option>
 <option value="1.24">1.24</option>
 </select>

 <select id="weight">
 <option value="38">38</option>
 <option value="39">39</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between selectors *option* and *attribute selector*, you should also wrap the values with quotation marks, otherwise you will get syntax errors for strings like `1.24`.

```
$("#"+key+ " option[value='"+p[key]+"']").prop('selected', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3DLbA/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space between "option" and "[value=..." - a space says "a child of this element".

`$('option [value="123"]')` matches (for example) `<option><label value="123">...`

`$('option[value="123"]')` matches `<option value="123">`

Answer (score 0):

**[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZrTZA/8/)**

I sees two errors in the code .. One is Remove the space between

```
option[value
      ^
    No space here
```

Next is Add Quotes to your value..

```
 if ($("#" + key + " option[value='" + p[key] + "']").length) {
      $("#" + key + " option[value='" + p[key] + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

**Encase your values in Single Quotes**

You dont have a value of  `option[value=1.24]`

```
       It should be `option[value='1.24']`
                                  ^    ^
                                 Missing Quotes here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZrTZA/8/